# rspec; How to test this function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec

**ImageManager.check_enable_time**

```
def check_enable_time
   # get current time
   now_time = Time.now
   # UTC to JST convestion JST = UTC + 9 hours
   hour = now_time.in_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").hour
   (hour != 23) ? true : false
```

end

This function return true if current time in JST != 23 else returns false.

I want to test this function.

**What I tried:**

```
 describe ImageManager do
  describe "Test check_enable_time() function" do
    context "When current time in JST != 23" do
      it 'should return true' do
        image_manager = ImageManager.new
        result = image_manager.check_enable_time
        result.should eql(true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How do make `now_time.in_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").hour` return 23 and other than 23?

Please help I am new to rails and rspec.

Comment: Just curious - why do you use `Time.now` and then converting in "Asia/Tokyo" zone? Do you know you could set default timezone in rails settings and then simply use `Time.current` without converting?

Comment: sorry i don't know. Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You can start from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#calculations and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration guides

Comment: Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stub current time using [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem:

```
  it 'should return true' do
    image_manager = ImageManager.new
    Timecop.travel(Time.local(2008, 9, 1, 12, 0, 0)) do
      result = image_manager.check_enable_time
    end
    result.should eql(true)
  end
```

Comment: This is not consistent with best practice. Please use let vars and expect syntax. http://www.betterspecs.org/#should

Comment: Agree, but I tried to show the only change topic starter was worried about.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that avoids installing another gem would be to rewrite your existing method so that it doesn't have an explicit dependency on Time.now:

```
def check_enable_time(now_time = Time.now)
  # UTC to JST convestion JST = UTC + 9 hours
  hour = now_time.in_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").hour
  (hour != 23) ? true : false
end
```

You could then test it by passing in the appropriate time:

```
it 'should return true' do
  image_manager = ImageManager.new
  time = Time.local(2008, 9, 1, 12, 0, 0)
  result = image_manager.check_enable_time(time)

  result.should eql(true)
end
```